# How to make Fsharp show Charting?

Tags: charts, f#, f#-data, fsharpchart

```
Chart.Line [ for x in 1.0 .. 100.0 -> (x, x ** 2.0) ]
```

I tried many times in order to see the Charting from Fsharp as [F# Charting](https://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/PointAndLineCharts.html)

I install some extensions which I think needed :

- Fsharp.Charting
- Fsharp.Chart
- Fsharp.Charting.Gtk
- Microsoft.Chart.Controls

But all it seems not enough for me to do . Could you give me some helpfull guide ? Thank you very much .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a fsharp script or source file (.fs or .fsx) and are you using Visual Studio or Vs Code?

Comment: Yes . I'm using Visual Emprise 2017

Comment: *If you were I , you can Uninstall + Install Visual Emprise .* 

This's reasons takes me many times . 

*Thank you everyone who help me in my difficulty .*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running this from F# Interactive and you are referencing the library using the recommended method, then the loading registers a handler with F# Interactive that will open charts automatically when you run the line that creates a chart. That is, load the library using:

```
#I "packages/FSharp.Charting"
#load "FSharp.Charting.fsx"
```

And then create chart using:

```
Chart.Line [ for x in 1.0 .. 100.0 -> (x, x ** 2.0) ]
```

If you are not inside a script, or if you are referencing just the `dll` (or if your editor handles F# Scripts differently than the standard editors - which I don't think should be the case), then you need to call `Show` method explicitly:

```
Chart.Line [ for x in 1.0 .. 100.0 -> (x, x ** 2.0) ]
|> Chart.Show
```

Comment: @AIRO2001 - Have you done a NuGet package restore, so that the `packages/FSharp.Charting` directory actually exists?

Comment: I had created a minimal repo here: https://github.com/xuanduc987/FSharpChartingMinimal

Comment: @AIRO2001 - I don't use Visual Studio so I can't walk you through the process, but basically, there's an option somewhere in the menus called "Restore NuGet packages" (the wording might be a little different). Once you've run that, you should look in the `packages` folder that will appear in your project, find the one with `FSharp.Charting` in the name, and reference that. **IMPORTANT**: You must make sure the folder name in the `#I` line is correct (it might have a version number in it). See http://brandewinder.com/2016/02/06/10-fsharp-scripting-tips/ for more information.

Comment: *If you were I , you can Uninstall + Install Visual Emprise .* 

This's reasons takes me many times . 

*Thank you everyone who help me in my difficulty .*

Answer (score 0):

Add System.Drawing reference to your project via: Right click on references >
Assemblies > FrameWork > System.Drawing

then try this code instead.

```
open FSharp.Charting

Chart.Line [ for x in 1.0 .. 100.0 -> (x, x ** 2.0) ]
|> Chart.Show

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 0
```

Comment: *If you were I , you can Uninstall + Install Visual Emprise .* 

This's reasons takes me many times . 

*Thank you everyone who help me in my difficulty .*

Answer (score 0):

*If you were I , you can Uninstall + Install Visual Emprise .*

This's reasons takes me many times .

*Thank you everyone who help me in my difficulty .*